# Push one array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner student. I have an array called shoppingCart declared at the start of .js .

```
var shoppingCart = [];
```

I think this is not the most appropriate and professional way to do it, but i don't know more.
And then I have the following function:

```
function addToShoppingCart(numProduct, quantity){
  shoppingCart.push([numProduct, quantity]);
}
```

With this function I want to add a new element, a two-element array, in the shoppingCart array.
I've also tried to do the following:

```
shoppingCart.push("["+ numProduct + ", " + quantity+ "]");
```

I want the array looks like this:

```
shoppingCart = [[numProduct1,quantity1],[numProduct2,quantity2],...,[numProductN,quantityN]]
```

But it seems to be added as individual elements. What am I doing wrong? How should I do it correctly?
Thank you for your help and/or attention.

Comment: What is wrong with `push([numProduct, quantity]);`? It should do exactly what you want.

Comment: What you wrote first should have worked. Are you sure you didn't do `shoppingCard.push(numProduct, quantity)`? That would add them separately instead of as an array.

Comment: `shoppingCart.push("["+ numProduct + ", " + quantity+ "]");` adds a **string** to `shoppingCart`, not an array. Strings are not evaluated as source code. `[a]` and `"[a]"` are two very different things.

Comment: That said, I recommend you use objects rather than arrays as the elements of the shopping cart. Arrays should be used for uniform data, objects should be used for heterogenous structures.

Comment: `shoppingCart.push({productid: numProduct, quantity: quantity})`

Comment: Unless im mistaken, all you need to do is call addToShoppingCart(numProduct, quantity) each time you want to add ot the cart.

Answer (score 3):

In general you should first create an object then populate and finally push it in the array:

```
function addToShoppingCart(numProduct, quantity){
  var product = {}
  product.number = numProduct;
  product.quantity = quantity
  shoppingCart.push(product);
  console.log(shoppingCart)
}
```

Now you have an array of objects as you can find out from the `console.log`

As @FelixKling suggested you can avoid the initialization of the empty object and just do: `shoppingCart.push({number: numProduct, quantity: quantity});`

Comment: What's the benefit of creating an empty object first?

Comment: Personally I find `{number: numProduct, quantity: quantity}` more readable. And in ES6 you can even do `{number, quantity}` to avoid typos.

Comment: @FelixKling added your comment in my answer